# SyntaxError: Missing catch or finally after try

Tags: javascript

How to fix "SyntaxError: Missing catch or finally after try"

I tried to make a scientific calculator and I get this error

```js
 function maths(a) {
        math = a;
        try {
            if (operatorSign =="+") {
                prep();
                firstI = first - second;
                mathematics(); 
                first = second + "+" + result;

            } else if (operatorSign =="-") {
                prep();
                firstI = second - first;
                mathematics();
                first = second + "-" +"("+result+")";

            } else if (operatorSign =="*") {
                prep();
                firstI = second / first;
                mathematics();
                first = second + "/" + result;

            } else {
                firstI = first;
                mathematics();
                first = result;
            }

            return first;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what's wrong: You have `try { /*...*/ }` and there's no `catch (e) { /*...*/ }` or `finally { /*...*/}` after it. There's no point to a `try` block without at least a `catch` or a `finally` (or both) following it (in that order), so trying to do that is a syntax error. The solution is to remove the `try` or add a `catch` and/or `finally`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Comment: I see you want to use `try`. What's your goal?

Comment: you should read more about error handling with javascrpit. you cannot use try without catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it is not easy to read what your code does. But you will need a catch block after the try block. You can find [documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch). Like in this short example where the function nonExistentFunction is absent and therefore the code will through an error. This is catch by the catch block. The catch block doesn't have to do anything (like mine is printing the error in the console).

```js
try {
  nonExistentFunction();
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's more or less like this:

```
try {
     someFunction();
} catch(err) {
     throw new Error(err);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! As it is currently written, your answer is unclear. Please edit it and add more details why and how it works. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.